# returning a pointer that points to char array. How do i print out the entire contents of the array?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reverse

This program reverses a given string but i can't seem to figure out how to return the entire buffer, all answers welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char  ReverseString(char *input);

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Please Enter a String: ";
    getline(cin,str);
    cout << "The string you entered is: " << str << endl;
    str = ReverseString(&str[0]);
    cout << str;
}

char  ReverseString(char* input)
{
    int size = strlen(input);
    char *it;
    char *revBuffer = new char[size];
    it = revBuffer;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
       *it = input[(size-1)-i];
       it++;
    }
    return *revBuffer; //
```

I can't seem to figure out how to return the entire buffer instead of just one element the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: `char  *ReverseString(char* input)` and `return revBuffer`; Or - better- return an `std::string`.

Comment: You are leaking a `char[]`.

Comment: Don't use arrays of char, use std::strings everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it does not make sense to declare an object of the type `std::string` and then to try to reverse it as a character array.

And moreover the header that contains declarations of standard C functions is named like `<cstring>`.

Also you need to include the header that contains the definition of the class `std::string`.

So the headers should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
```

However a question arises: why not to use the same object of the type `std::string` instead of interpreting it as a character array?

Your approach even if to make it to compile has in any case bugs. Due to this statement

```
str = ReverseString(&str[0]);
```

there is a memory leak. And moreover the returned string is not zero-terminated.

Thus the program has undefined behavior.

In fact what you are trying to do is to copy one string in another string in the reversed order.

Using objects of the type `std::string` the task can be done in one line.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("Hello, World!");
    std::string t( s.rbegin(), s.rend() );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello, World!
!dlroW ,olleH
```

if you want to reverse the original string then you could write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("Hello, World!");

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    s.assign( s.rbegin(), s.rend() );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can write a separate function the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string ReverseCopyString( const std::string &s )
{
    return { s.rbegin(), s.rend() };
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("Hello, World!");
    std::string t = ReverseCopyString( s );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy` that does the same task. Or if you want to reverse the original string then you can use the algorithm `std::reverse`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s("Hello, World!");
    std::string t;
    t.reserve(s.size());

    std::reverse_copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(t));

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to deal with character arrays then the original string should also be stored in a character array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

char * ReverseCopyString(const char *s)
{
    size_t n = std::strlen(s);

    char *t = new char[n + 1];

    size_t i = 0;

    for (; i != n; i++) t[i] = s[n - 1 - i];

    t[i] = '\0';

    return t;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char s[N];

    std::cout << "Please Enter a String: ";
    std::cin.getline(s, sizeof( s ) );

    std::cout << "The string you entered is: " << s << std::endl;

    char *t = ReverseCopyString( s );

    std::cout << t << std::endl;

    delete []t;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Please Enter a String: Hello, World!
The string you entered is: Hello, World!
!dlroW ,olleH
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation was very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a char instead of a char*. A char is always just a single character. If you want to get a string back return a string or a char*.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using std::string, so why not use it to reverse the string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string ReverseString(std::string const &str)
{
    return std::string(str.crbegin(), str.crend());
}

int main()
{
    std::string str("1234");
    std::cout << ReverseString(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
4321
```

Comment: THANK YOU is there a way to do this with out using std::string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things. Either you can choose to return a char*. The code of which is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char  *ReverseString(char *input);

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Please Enter a String: ";
    getline(cin,str);
    cout << "The string you entered is: " << str << endl;
    str = ReverseString(&str[0]);
    cout << str;
}

char *ReverseString(char* input)
{
    int size = strlen(input);
    char *it;
    char *revBuffer = new char[size];
    it = revBuffer;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
       *it = input[(size-1)-i];
       it++;
    }
    return revBuffer;
}
```

Or, you can print the string in your fuction only. The code of which is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void  ReverseString(char *input);

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Please Enter a String: ";
    getline(cin,str);
    cout << "The string you entered is: " << str << endl;
    ReverseString(&str[0]);

}

void  ReverseString(char* input)
{
    int size = strlen(input);
    char *it;
    char *revBuffer = new char[size];
    it = revBuffer;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
       *it = input[(size-1)-i];
       it++;
    }
    cout << revBuffer;  
}
```

The code is self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I chose to go with the first approach returning a char*. Now the program prints the reversed string, but it also prints some random characters along with it.

Comment: here are some outputs.                                                                         
        Please Enter a String: hi
       The string you entered is: hi
        ih.▒

Answer (score -1):

Your function is set to return a single character `char` and that's what you've done, you've returned the first char of the reversed string by de-referencing the `revBuffer` pointer which is a pointer to the first element of the char array.

What you need to do is to set your function to return a pointer `char*` instead of a `char` and so you can return `revBuffer`.

So your code should look like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

//Function return a char pointer instead of a char
char*  ReverseString(char *input);

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Please Enter a String: ";
    getline(cin,str);
    cout << "The string you entered is: " << str << endl;
    str = ReverseString(&str[0]);
    cout << str;
}

char*  ReverseString(char* input)
{
    int size = strlen(input);
    char *it;
    char *revBuffer = new char[size+1];
    it = revBuffer;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
       *it = input[(size-1)-i];
       it++;
    }
    *it = '\0';
    //return a pointer to the reversed string
    return revBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Hey so I fixed my function to return a char*, but now when i print to console I'm getting the reversed string with some other random characters. Could it be my pointer arithmetic? i don't see anything wrong with it. Thanks alot.

Comment: That happened cause you didn't add the NULL terminating character `\0` at the end of the reversed string.

Comment: @monkhii NULL terminating character ADDED, check the code once again.